# Simplest way to fix variables spacing? [php]

Tags: php, attributes, spacing

I'm trying to create a very basic multiplication table without the actual table element, but not sure how to space the numbers correctly (without using css or an html table!). What's the simplest way to do this?

```html
<?php

  for ($i=1; $i < 11 ; $i++) {

    for ($x=1; $x< 11 ; $x++) {
      echo  $i*$x . " ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
  }

 ?>
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this good enough

```
>     <?php for ($i=1; $i < 11 ; $i++) {
>     for ($x=1; $x< 11 ; $x++) {
>         $output = $i*$x;
>         if($output >= 10){
>             echo $output . str_repeat('&nbsp;', 4);
>         } else{
>             echo $output .  str_repeat('&nbsp;', 6); ;
>         }
>     }
>     echo "<br>"; } ?>

OUTPUT
```

[image]

Comment: I think SO talking about horizontal space to equal all .

Comment: I changed it horizontaly

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is, that the numbers do not fit in the "columns" than that could help. It prints spaces after the numbers so that you always have 3 digits/characters.

```
<?php

  for ($i=1; $i < 11 ; $i++) {

    for ($x=1; $x< 11 ; $x++) {
      echo  $i*$x;
      for($y=0; $y < 3-strlen((string)$i*$y)) { echo " "; }
    }
    echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

But to use table Tags would be the best way.